# How to link inside a Rails 3.1 engine from within main_app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way in Rails to link inside an engine from within the main_app?

In my application I have

```
resources :organizations do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"

  resources :projects do
    mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"
  end
end
```

MyEngine adds tasks management to either organizations or projects. 
`main_app.organization_my_engine_path` will link to `/organizations/1/my_engine`
`main_app.organization_project_my_engine_path` will link to `/organizations/1/projects/1/my_engine`

Is there a way, from the main application and given a task, to create a link to 
`/organizations/1/my_engine/tasks/1`, and similarly for the projects?